# Connecting two physical computer's monitors together

Tags: multiple-monitors

I've been pushing the envelope with Linux for some time now. My latest feat is trying to take two separate computers with two separate monitors and conjoin their monitors so to easily drag icons that land on one of  my /home/./Desktop to the other /home/./Desktop and versa and since I have the same background on both of them, it helps the illusion that they're connected together.

Answer (score 0):

I think the closest you can get is controlling both computers with the same physical keyboard and mouse. You can move your cursor between the different computers as if they were one, but I don't know about the file transfer. There is a rather useful program called Synergy that lets you do what I described above. You can get it for free and it works, but the set up is a bit complicated, and it doesn't work well with dual monitors (on one computer). If you want to check it out, here are some links, one to the site, and the other to the download. If you need any help, feel free to comment.

[Main website](http://synergy-project.org/)

[Download(64-bit)](http://download.cnet.com/Synergy-for-Ubuntu-and-Debian-64-bit/3000-2072_4-75628906.html)

Sorry for the slightly short answer. If you need more detail, just tell me.